# I cant switch the boolean from true to false even though I have it written correctly

Tags: javascript, boolean, discord, discord.js, boolean-expression

canChat seems to not acutally switch from false to true, or true to false when I run 'switch,' while it should! I've looked it up to make sure and it seems that I'm correct!

````
//deletes a  message sent by someone if canChat is false
let canChat = new Boolean(false);
    if(message.author.id.substring(0) === '475418097990500362' && !canChat){
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('we\'re sorry, this bot it no longer available. Please stop using it.');
    }
    
    //Current Commands
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'switch' :
            canChat = !canChat; //This is what isn't working!
            if(canChat){
                message.reply('Switched to true');
            } else { message.reply('Switched to false');}
            break;```
````

Comment: A Boolean object and a boolean primitive are much different. You should be setting `canChat` to just plain `false`.

Answer (score 0):

as pointy mention a Boolean [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Constructor)/[primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) are two separate things.

Try the below edit

```js
let canChat = false;
if(message.author.id.substring(0) === '475418097990500362' && !canChat){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`canChat` it is an object in your example:

```
let canChat = new Boolean(false);
if (canChat) {
    //it will be executed despite of false
}
```

You can just use true and false primitive values

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean